# Recognize user inactivity and/or lock sceen in bash scripts

Tags: lock-screen, monitoring, idle

In Xubuntu 18.04LTS, I test the capability to capture screen in background without [interacting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083128/take-screenshots-in-background-silently-for-archive-purposes/1083229#1083229) with the tool.

To optimize this, how is it possible to:

- Recognize whether user is inactive since more than X seconds;
- Or the lock screen is on.